# How to write select query for this?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have column `COMPONENT_AMOUNT(money)` ,`MONTH_FOR(int)`, `YEAR_FOR(int)` and `COMPONENT_TYPE(int)`. I want to find the sum of amount according to condition. I have written my query like this but it solve my purpose.

My purpose is that if one select Nov-2010 then it will sum the amount up to this selected month including all the month of 2009.

My query is given below ,please modify it:

```
SELECT SUM(Convert(Numeric(7,2), Round([COMPONENT_AMOUNT],2,1))) 
FROM [TEAM_FUNDS_DETAILS] 
WHERE YEAR_FOR <= 1 AND MONTH_FOR <= 1 AND [COMPONENT_TYPE] = 1
```

Comment: how do you store years in YEAR_FOR columns. For example what will be its value for 2009 and 2010?

Comment: @Faisal Feroz:using index like 2009 is=0 and 2010=1

Comment: please add the tag. You can use up to 5 tags per question. Please don't scrimp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If You need only one result per query I think that this is code

```
declare @year int 
declare @month int

set @year = 2010 --desire year
set @month = 8   --desire month

select sum(COMPONENT_AMOUNT)
from [TEAM_FUNDS_DETAILS] 
WHERE
    [COMPONENT_TYPE] = 1
    and  (
           YEAR_FOR < @year
        or (year_for=@year and month_for<=@month)
          )
```